# Process not showing up in Applescript "name of every process"

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write some applescript that sees if a particular process is running on my computer and then give the user the option to kill the process if they want (the program I'm looking for if it's relevant is [videosnap](https://github.com/matthutchinson/videosnap)

When I run the following code:

```
tell application "System Events"
set processList to name of every process
end tell

if "videosnap" is in ProcessList then
-rest of code-
```

The only problem is that videosnap doesn't show up in the process list - I can't figure out why as it shows up in apple's activity monitor. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: System Events only lists processes that have a GUI connection. (Which is understandable since AppleScript isn't much good for working with anything else.) Swot up on shell scripting and use `ps` and `kill`/`killall`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking for it with ps?

```
set xxx to do shell script "ps -ax"
```

Comment: I haven't done much with ps but it looks like it gets me very close to what I'm looking for, I should be able to search through that after correct?